# Scopes Causing undefined method `const_defined?'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Here's my scopes:

```
scope :parents, where("categories.parent_category_id IS NULL")
scope :children_of, lambda { |parent| where("categories.parent_category_id = ?", parent) }
```

I'm not totally sure what's wrong with them though. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

### Update:

This is the error...

```
undefined method `const_defined?' for #<Category:0x112ccfdb8>
```

And here's the full trace: https://gist.github.com/1186122

Comment: Could you post the error message?

Comment: app/views/categories/show.html.erb:17, can you paste this line of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the gem acts_as_tree used in the Category model which was breaking the scopes I was making. It's all fixed now. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Having a scope called `parents` also breaks `acts_as_nested_set` v1.4.4

Answer (score 2):

It looks like having a scope called `parents` breaks if you have acts_as_tree v0.1.1 with rails 3.0.10.